# FutureBuilder returns no data but "Instance of Object"

Tags: flutter, sqflite

i'm currently working on a app which basically works like a database. I want it to fetch data from my sqflite database and use it as text. For some reason I only get "Index of Object" instead of the correct value as text. This is my code in database_helper.dart:

```
  Future<Obj> getName(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await  db.query(table, columns: [objName], where: "objId= ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    await print(res);         //returns right value
    return await res.isNotEmpty ? Fish.fromMap(res.first) : Null ;
  }
}
```

and this is my FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: dbHelper.getName(1),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.message),
                    title: Text('${snapshot.data}'),
                    subtitle: Text(""),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()),
                      );
                    }
                    );
            }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
```

I feel like I tried everything. Printing res directly from database_helper.dart gives the right result. 
I'd love some tipps! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FutureBuilder is working fine and is returning data.You have one Fish object returned from your getName future.
*snapshot.data* has returned one Fish object.To show any property you can use snapshot.data.propertyName of Fish Model.